# Alt-tab menu not showing when in fullscreen

Tags: ubuntu, fullscreen, alt-tab, sublime-text

When I use Sublime text 3 in fullscreen (F11) mode and use alt+tab, the menu doesn't show. This is rather frustrating, since I'm unable to predict which window I'm switching to. Is there any way to change this behaviour or some way I can change my working habits to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the dev branch of sublime and is for now only available to people who run a registered version. To get the fix change to the dev channel as described here https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html and update to the latest version.